# Get time using cookies javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

How to get Time with Cookies javascript When I close the tab or Page?
i'm try use window.onunload but time can not be stored in cookies..
in this code i'm push my cookies to be array

```
setCookie("time",time,1)
window.onunload  =function (){
    var set = getCookie('time');
    var arr = [];
    var push = arr.push(set);
    console.log (arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there is a class called "Date" that let's you get the current time.

`var d = new Date();` creates a new `Date` object and assigns it to the variable `d`

Now, you have the date and time - you can do whatever you like.

For example: `document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = d.toString()` finds the element with the ID of "foo" and sets it's contents to the date and time.

Keep in mind that this date and time display will not constantly update itself. You will have to do that with some timed recursion.

There are many more things you can do with dates. Remember, Google is your friend - look up some things about the `Date` object.